# check if a customer is online magento

Tags: php, magento

first please pardon me if my question seems a bit off but I will appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction or a sample or code that can get all currently logged in customers online programmatically.

I already found out that you can use

```
Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn()
```

to find out if the current user is logged in or not but what I am asking is to check a particular user else where from his id to know if he/she is logged in or not.

and I have already posted a similar question on the magento forum incase you find out but no response yet at least till the time of this post. via this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/300354/

any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you want to know every customers currently logged in, this code  (from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Online_Grid`) should do it:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('log/visitor_online')
        ->prepare()
        ->getCollection();
    /* @var $collection Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor_Online_Collection */
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('notnull' => true))->addCustomerData();
```

If you want to check about a particular user, replace `array('notnull' => true)` by the id of this customer and check if the `count()` of the collection is 1.

Comment: you are just too much that did the job perfectly as i wanted thanks a lot @OSdave.

Answer (score 0):

Ref https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php#L140 :

```
Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->getCustomerId();
```

Comment: this will only return my own id as a customer id but i want a situation that i can supply a particular id to a function and the function checks if the customer is online like isOnline($anyCusmtomerID); returns true or false

Answer (score 0):

Old question...Anyway I think that the best way to check if a single user is online, is to take inspiration from the code in `app/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php`.
The following lines are taken from different parts of this file.
Basically we check against the logout and the last visit time taking advantage of the `Mage_Log_Model_Customer` and the `Mage_Log_Model_Visitor` models.

```
$id = "<CUSTOMER_ID>";
// Here make your tests about the ID, if the user exists, etc...
$customerLog = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($id);
return !($customerLog->getLogoutAt() ||
    strtotime(now())-strtotime($customerLog->getLastVisitAt())>Mage_Log_Model_Visitor::getOnlineMinutesInterval()*60);
```